# Need to use html form select input on other html pages within the site

Tags: java, html, forms

The index page of the site will ask user to select a stage area.  I want to pass their selection from page to page until they log out or return to this selection.
I have searched long and hard but just don't know how to phrase that question to a web search.  Just need a little push in the right direction.  Form code below and thanks in advance.

```
<form name="pick" method="POST" action="http://wavepick.htm">
<table border="0">
  <tr VALIGN="TOP">
    <td width="177">

<select id="stageChoice" name="stageArea">
<option selected value=" ">(Select Staging Area)</option>
<option value="A">A </option>
<option value="B">B </option>
</select> 
</div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Stage" name="B1">
<input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="wavepick">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to store it in a session after submitting the form?

Comment: Possibly.  End result is I need to pass the value of this selection around from page to page via the links so all my links will be like <a title="AnySucessiveLink" href="http://theNextPage.htm&THEVALUE">Next Page</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a backend language such as PHP you can store that value in a $_SESSION variable. and access it wherever you need during that session.

Here is the documentation for the session variables:

[PHP Session](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)

If not, let me know and i'll figure out a different method for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected value between pages in a [session variable](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this only with HMTL/Javascript, you have to submit this form via "GET" (instead "POST"), and at each page you need to send again "stageArea" to the another page, so:

- Page1.html?stageArea=B
- Page2.html?stageArea=B
- Page3.html?stageArea=B

That's how you read GET parameters via Javascript: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Ya, it's very arduous just with HTML/Javscript.

But you have mentioned "log out", do you have **back-end** (like PHP, ASP.NET,etc..)? With back-end language it'll be much more easier, you could store stageArea on **session** once, and just read it at each page.